# Reorder an array to get the last first in table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Let´s say my array looks like this:

```
let test = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

In the tableView, it will look like this:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5

But I want it to look like this:

> 5
>
> 4
>
> 3
>
> 2
>
> 1

I am using this for the cell.text:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = dataArray[indexPath.row] as? String
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you think of a relation between `indexPath.row` and the index of the array element that should be displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should work.

```
dataArray[dataArray.count - 1 - indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked fine :)

Comment: This is dangerous. What if `dataArray` is empty?

Comment: @MarcusRossel: This is not more or less dangerous than `dataArray[indexPath.row]` or `reversedDataArray[indexPath.row]`. If the array is empty then `numberOfRowsInSection` returns zero and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not called at all.

Comment: Depends on the implementation of `numberOfRowsInSection`. If it is indeed as simple as `return dataArray.count`, then it's fine. But we have no idea what it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

`Array` conforms to `CollectionType`, which adds a default implementation of a method called [`reverse`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_CollectionType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/CollectionType/s:FeRq_Ss14CollectionTypeqq_Ss9Indexable5IndexSs21RandomAccessIndexType_SsS_7reverseuRq_S_qq_S0_5IndexS1__Fq_FT_GVSs29ReverseRandomAccessCollectionq__):

```
@warn_unused_result func reverse() -> ReverseCollection<Self>
@warn_unused_result func reverse() -> ReverseRandomAccessCollection<Self>
```

You can call `test.reverse()`, and use the result to get a reversed array.

Comment: Thanks, but where do i put the: `@warn_unused_result func reverse() -> ReverseCollection<Self>` code?

Comment: it's something like this:
`var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
// Reverse its contents
array = array.reverse()`

Comment: As @FilippoCamillo said: You reverse the array, by simply calling `text.reverse()`. The code I've posted just shows the function definitions of the methods. You do not have to implement these methods yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward in swift:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
array = array.reverse()
print(array) -> [6,5,4,3,2,1]
```